# How to add a unique index between two references columns in Rails Migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I have the following migration:

```
create_table :product_attr_vals do |t|
  t.references :product, foreign_key: true
  t.references :attr_val, foreign_key: true

  t.timestamps
end
```

How can I add a unique index for the both `t.references`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to the following:

```
create_table :product_attr_vals do |t|
  t.references :product, foreign_key: true
  t.references :attr_val, foreign_key: true

  t.timestamps
end

# Add this line
add_index :product_attr_vals, [:product_id, : attr_val_id], unique: true
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, @fongfan999. Is there any difference between what you posted and using `t.index [:product_id, :attr_val_id], unique: true` (adding `index: true` after each t.references)?

Comment: `t.index [:product_id, :attr_val_id], unique: true` is as same as my posted, but adding `index: true` after each t.references is totally wrong.

Comment: Thank you again for the second answer ;).